# Obter dados de uma tabela dinâmica no Excel

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando realizar a leitura de uma planilha em excel e estou criando uma tabela dinâmica via programação e está dando certo, porém estou tendo problema para pegar esses dados filtrados, pois não retorna todos os itens que foram filtrados com a quantidade maior que 0 (Zero).

**P.S.:** Delphi XE-2

Exemplo do excel que estou usando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
uses ComObj;

var
  ExcelApp, ExcelSheetApp: OleVariant;
  Dados: Variant;
  LastLin, LastCol, ColQuantidade: Integer;      
  opgFile: TOpenDialog;
const
  xlCellTypeLastCell= $0000000B;
  xlCellTypeVisible = $0000000C;
  Excel = 'Excel.Application';
begin
  if MessageDlg('Deseja importar os produtos de uma planilha?', mtConfirmation, mbYesNo, 0, mbNo) = mrYes then      
    begin
      try
        opgFile := TOpenDialog.Create(Self);
        opgFile.Filter := 'Excel|*.xls*';
        if opgFile.Execute then
        begin
          ColQuantidade:=3;
          {Obteve as informações do excel}
          ExcelApp := CreateOleObject(Excel);
          ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Open(opgFile.FileName);
          ExcelApp.visible := True; {Somente para teste}
          ExcelSheetApp := ExcelApp.WorkBooks[1].WorkSheets[1];
          {Obtem a ultima linha}
          ExcelSheetApp.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;
          LastLin := ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Row;
          LastCol := ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Column;
          {Filtra pela coluna Quantidade}
          ExcelSheetApp.Range['A1', ExcelApp.Cells.Item[LastLin, LastCol]].AutoFilter(Field := ColQuantidade, Criteria1 := '<>',
            Criteria2 := '<>0');
          {Obtem somente as linhas visibeis}
          ExcelSheetApp.Range['A1', ExcelApp.Cells.Item[LastLin, LastCol]].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible, EmptyParam).Activate;

          Dados := ExcelSheetApp.Range['A1', ExcelApp.Cells.Item[LastLin, LastCol]].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible, EmptyParam).value;
           {O problema ocorre aqui, pois não retorna todos os itens filtrados}
        end;
      finally
        if not VarIsEmpty(ExcelApp) then
        begin
          ExcelApp.Quit;
          ExcelApp := Unassigned;
          ExcelSheetApp := Unassigned;
        end;
        if Assigned(opgFile) then
          FreeAndNil(opgFile);
      end;
```

Comment: Poderia fornecer o xls, para simular o seu problema exato aqui ?

Comment: "Tá dando problema". Qual problema? A sua pergunta não está clara (tanto que o colega @VictorZanella , com muuuiiiita boa vontade, teve que pedir o xls para simular o seu problema! Ele não devia ter que fazer isso!). Esse site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, *principalmente*, leia [ask].

Comment: Você comentou no código fonte que não retorna todos os dados filtrados, então alguma coisa da tabela dinâmica retorna? Na linha onde ocorre o problema, quais os valores das variáveis _LastLin_ e _LastCol_?

Comment: O _LastLin_ e _LastCol_ ele pega do excel, as ultimas linhas e colunas que possuam informação.
          `LastLin := ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Row;`
          `LastCol := ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Column;`
Oque eu consegui perceber é que quando é feito o filtro no excel, como por exemplo o excel que eu enviei, na linha 9 eu coloquei um produto com quantidade 0. O retorno da função do excel que retorna somente as linhas visíveis ele não retorna todas as posições da matriz, somente até a linha 8.

Comment: @LuizVieira, Bom no fonte foi dito que `{O problema ocorre aqui, pois não retorna todos os itens filtrados}`

Comment: `LastLin=21` e `LastCol=3` @Andrey

Comment: Bom, eu admito que não reparei nesse comentário dentro do código. Retirei o meu voto pra fechar. De todas as formas, não custava nada você ter deixado a indicação *também* fora do código, no corpo da pergunta (algo como: "na linha XX, a função YYY não retorna os itens filtrados"). Evitaria justamente precisar desse tipo de esclarecimento. Fica a dica pro futuro. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, pronto, adicionei no corpo da pergunta! Thks pela dica!